# AttributeError: 'FirstTab' object has no attribute 'backBTN'

Tags: python, pyqt5

Buenos días. Estos días he estoy haciendo un navegador con pestañas hecho con PyQt5 (Python) pero me sale este error: **AttributeError: 'FirstTab' object has no attribute 'backBTN'**.Creo Que este error se debe a algo relacionado con la clases o algo parecido.
He intentado de todo pero me sigue saliendo el mismo error
Este código por si alguien lo necesita para que el que me intente ayudar:

````
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon,QFont
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QWidget,QPushButton,QVBoxLayout, QTabWidget, QLabel,QMainWindow,QLineEdit,QPushButton, QApplication,QToolBar
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize,QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage, QWebEngineView

class TabDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Tab Widget Application")
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("icon.png"))

        tabwidget = QTabWidget()
        tabwidget.addTab(FirstTab(), "First Tab")
        tabwidget.addTab(TabTwo(), "Second Tab")

        vboxLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        vboxLayout.addWidget(tabwidget)

        self.setLayout(vboxLayout)

class FirstTab(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(self)
        backButton= QPushButton()
        backButton.setIcon(QIcon("icons/back.png"))
        backButton.setIconSize(QSize(36,36))
        backButton.clicked.connect(self.backBTN)

        
        reloadButton= QPushButton()
        reloadButton.setIcon(QIcon("icons/reload.png"))
        reloadButton.setIconSize(QSize(36,36))
        reloadButton.clicked.connect(self.reloadBTN)



        f1_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        f1_layout.addWidget(backButton)
        f1_layout.addWidget(reloadButton)
        self.setLayout(backButton)



def searchBTN(self):
    self.webEngineView.load(QUrl("https://web.whatsapp.com/"))
    
def backBTN(self):
    self.webEngineView.back()
    
def forwardBTN(self):
    self.webEngineView.forward()
    
def reloadBTN(self):
    self.webEngineView.reload()
    
def homeBTN(self):
    self.webEngineView.load(QUrl("https://google.com"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    tabdialog = TabDialog()
    tabdialog.show()
    app.exec()```
````

Answer (score 0):

Prueba así:

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon,QFont
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QWidget, \
    QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QTabWidget, QLabel, QMainWindow, \
    QLineEdit, QPushButton, QApplication, QToolBar, QGridLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize,QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage, QWebEngineView


class FirstTab(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()                                         # - self
        
        backButton= QPushButton('back')
        backButton.setIcon(QIcon("icons/back.png"))
        backButton.setIconSize(QSize(36,36))
        backButton.clicked.connect(self.backBTN)
        
        reloadButton= QPushButton('reload')
        reloadButton.setIcon(QIcon("icons/reload.png"))
        reloadButton.setIconSize(QSize(36,36))
        reloadButton.clicked.connect(self.reloadBTN)
        
        self.webEngineView = QWebEngineView()

        f1_layout = QGridLayout(self)                               # + self
        f1_layout.addWidget(backButton, 0, 0)
        f1_layout.addWidget(reloadButton, 0, 1)
        f1_layout.addWidget(self.webEngineView, 1, 0, 1, 2)
#        self.setLayout(backButton)

        self.homeBTN()                                              # +

#---->
    def searchBTN(self):
        self.webEngineView.load(QUrl("https://web.whatsapp.com/"))
        
    def backBTN(self):
        self.webEngineView.back()
        
    def forwardBTN(self):
        self.webEngineView.forward()
        
    def reloadBTN(self):
        self.webEngineView.reload()
        
    def homeBTN(self):
        self.webEngineView.load(QUrl("https://google.com"))
    

class TabDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Tab Widget Application")
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("icon.png"))

        tabwidget = QTabWidget()
        tabwidget.addTab(FirstTab(), "First Tab")
# ???        tabwidget.addTab(TabTwo(), "Second Tab")

        vboxLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        vboxLayout.addWidget(tabwidget)
        self.setLayout(vboxLayout)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    tabdialog = TabDialog()
    tabdialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]